# Subtracting pointers from nullptr doesn't yield expected value

Tags: c++, pointers, undefined-behavior

Why does some pointer math cause ambiguous results between compilers?

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    int * test = new int{100};
    int * a = nullptr;
    auto diff = test - a;
    int * test_copy = diff + a;
    return *test_copy;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/GvfG1M

- GCC thinks the result is 100.
- Clang thinks the result is 132.
- MSVC thinks the result is also not 100.

Comment: "...causing ambigious results between compilers." That's usually a sign of undefined behavior.

Comment: if you look at the [generated assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/11jbxx) you will see that clang generates `ud2` instruction for main, i.e. the program has undefined behavior.

Comment: This wasn't a question. It was a Q&A to attempt explain this undefined behaviour for others. StackOverflow encourages this every time you post a question.

Answer (score 1):

The result of subtracting two pointers that do not point to elements of the same array is *undefined*. (One beyond the end of the array is allowed, and for this purposes an object is considered to be a single element array.)

You can define it by casting each pointer to an integral type:

```
auto res = (std::ptrdiff_t)test - (std::ptrdiff_t)a;
```

but alas the result of doing even that is implementation defined.

---

A compiler is required to issue a diagnostic if two pointer types are summed.

Comment: Please use `reinterpret_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>` for stuff like this!

Comment: @Ben. Why? (The rules for interpreting a C-style cast are extremely clear by the standard and every C++ programmer will know them). You shouldn't really be doing either!

Comment: @Bathsheba It's generally better to use `reinterpret_cast` instead of C style casts because they are less powerful and the compiler can warn you about some mistakes. For example if you might accidentally cast away `const` with C style casts while you can't with `reinterpret_cast`. Generally, it is recommended to use the least powerful cast that achieves the required outcome to favor the odds that mistakes are caught by the compiler.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Methinks this debate will rumble on until the next general purpose language emerges. There ain't one close to C++ yet. There is, as I'm sure you know, a school of thought that suggests that *all* casts are down to a mistake.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'm curious what the pro-C style cast side of that debate would be. I was not aware that there was such a debate, I've never heard a compelling argument for their use over C style casts. The only argument I've heard for them is brevity, which is not compelling.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The pro simple cast side is probably mostly: Don't over-complicate things needlessly, it's *already* clear. While the other side is: We have to spell it all out with as much detail as possible because someone somewhere could someday be confused and not mean it. While we are at it, let's also ban all implicit conversions. And while for the complicated cases, I sympathise, for the blatantly obvious ones it's just an eyesore. (Yes, there is a bit of attitude in the characterisation of the positions. You may keep it. ;-))

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Though for const-correctness also speaks that you sometimes need different code. I admit to having (and also using) `implicit_cast` in my toolbelt anyway.

Comment: @Deduplicator I guess I asked for a point of view, and I got it. Even if I disagree with it. I've removed my comment objecting to it. Thanks.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Imho it's a matter of balance, not overcomplicating the simple cases, but being careful to sufficiently specify the iffy ones. Blanket bans are easier, and thus more often codified. As an aside, `F(one_argument)` *is* a C-style cast, using function-notation, but still fairly common in most codebases, undermining the insistence on always being fully explicit.

Comment: @Deduplicator The benefit of C style casts seems to be its simplicity. I guess I don't see why `(int)x` would be considered simpler than `static_cast<int>(x)`. It seems to me like brevity is being confused with simplicity. In terms of what they are, C style casts are the most complicated cast there is. The rules for explicit type conversions are more elaborate than every other C++ cast.

Comment: @Bathsheba the best reason here is type safety: Given a `float*`, `x`, what does  `(std::ptrdiff_t) *x` evaluate to? It casts the pointed-to `float` to a signed integer. Whereas `reinterpret_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(*x)` is a compile error, forcing you to either do `reinterpret_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(&x)` (get the pointer value as an integer) or `static_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(x)` (or just let `x` implicitly convert to `std::ptrdiff_t`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the pointer doesn't point to the same object. It is undefined behaviour to apply `operator+` or `operator-` to pointers that arn't part of the same object.

`test` is from global `operator new`. `nullptr` is not part of the memory managed by global `operator new`. These are two seperate things being pointed too.

If instead `a` and `test` are from a buffer`int[]` they are from the same object, no problem.

```
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    int buff[2]{100, 0};
    int * test = &buff[0];
    int * a = &buff[1];
    auto diff = test - a;
    int * test_copy = diff + a;
    return *test_copy;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5M9TTM

Now compilers seem to be happy.

Comment: @DavidLedger: My post's still up. I deleted it for a moment as I couldn't remember if the cast result was implementation defined or unspecified.

Comment: Edited to use same object in either case for a clearer answer.

Comment: agreed, thanks for the help. The only purpose of this post was to help people avoid this mistake... So its important that its clear. :)